# Laravel Pivot table vs additional Model

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

In my project i need users to be able to add other users as favorites.

Originally i have table **'users'**.
And now i think of 2 approaches:

1 - Crate pivot table **'favorite_users'**, with fields:

**'author_user_id'** (refers to **'id'** column on **'users'** table)

**'favourite_user_id'** (refers to **'id'** column on **'users'** table)

or

2 - Create a new Model **'FavoriteUser'** (with new table **'favorite_users'**) and link it to the **'User'** model using 2 relationships: **hasMany** and **belongsTo**.

Which option would be right for this situation or better?

Comment: Laravel idea for pivot in using their methods on relations `withPivot` `wherePivot` etc.
But if you feel more comfortable with additional model you can create it.

Comment: Both are valid approaches, it really depends on what you prefer.